# Unable to get ExtensionSidebarPane.setObject to work

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to modify the debugtools elements panel to add my own custom data. That data is not related to the web page DOM of the page being inspected. I want to put my own stuff there.

So, I did the following:

```
function createDebug(token)

    {
        console.log("createDebug() " + token);
        chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
            "Token Details: " + token,
            function(sidebar) {
              function updateElementProperties() {
                console.log("updateElementProperties()");
                var data = {};
                data.token = token;
                var s = JSON.stringify(data);
                console.log(s);
                sidebar.setObject(s, "DATA");
              }
              console.log("createSidebarPane() callback");
              updateElementProperties();
        });
    }
```

When I open the devtools, I just see the object that I set on the "DATA" subitem of "Token Details" panel.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess documentation is confusing with `extensionSidebarPane.setObject(string jsonObject, string rootTitle, function callback)` it has to be some thing like `extensionSidebarPane.setObject( jsonObject, string rootTitle, function callback)`.

becasue of this you are explicitly converting it to string using [JSON.stringify()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc836459%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

```
var data = {};
data.token = token;
var s = JSON.stringify(data);
console.log(s);
```

I have eliminated the last lines `var s = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log(s);` and it is working.

[image]

**Demonstration**

Using your function i got it working with following code.

***manifest.json***

Registered `devtools.html` to the manifest

```
{
  "name": "Dev Tools",
  "description":"This demonstrates dev tools API",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version":2,
  "devtools_page": "devtools.html"

}
```

***devtools.html***

Trivial `devtools.html` using `devtools.js`

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="devtools.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***devtools.js***

Eliminated explicit string tokenizing.

```
function createDebug(token){
    console.log("createDebug() " + token);
        chrome.devtools.panels.elements.createSidebarPane(
            "Token Details: " + token,
            function(sidebar) {
              function updateElementProperties() {
                console.log("updateElementProperties()");
                var data = {};
                data.token = token;
                //Commenting out explicit string conversion
                //var s = JSON.stringify(data);
                //console.log(s);
                sidebar.setObject(data, "DATA");
              }
              console.log("createSidebarPane() callback");
              updateElementProperties();
    });

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function (){
    createDebug("Trivial Token one");
});
```

Let me know if you need more information